# How do I get Android client side callback to fire after Firebase Cloud Function onWrite finishes?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I'm on a user page and I'd like to let users create a post but fanout on the server side.

```
exports.fanoutUpdatePost = functions.database.ref('/post/{postKey}').onWrite(event => {
        var post = event.data.val();

        var fanoutObject = {};

        fanoutObject['/user-post/'+post.userKey+'/post/'+event.params.postKey] = post;
        fanoutObject['/blog-post/'+post.blogKey+'/post/'+event.params.postKey] = post;

       return event.data.adminRef.root.update(fanoutObject);
});
```

---

I'm doing this so you can just post on `/post/` and the server will automatically fanout.
The problem is that I want the client side to show progress bar until it gets saved in `/user-post/`.

But my client side callback fires immediately after post gets created on `/post/`.

---

```
public void addPost(final PostDao post, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    String key = mDatabase.child(“post”).push().getKey();

    Map<String, Object> postUpdateMap = new HashMap<>();
    postUpdateMap.put(“/post/” +key, post.toMap());

    mDatabase.updateChildren(postUpdateMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if(databaseError == null){
                        Log.e(TAG, databaseError);
                    }else{
                        // @@@@@ This executes before server side 
                        // @@@@@ cloud function fanoutUpdatePost 
                        // @@@@@ finishes. Can I make this happen 
                        // @@@@@ after it?
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Is there a way to wait until my onWrite cloud function finishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific use-case I'd recommend Doug's approach.

But an alternative can be to think of your database as a bunch of request/response queues. So instead of creating a blog post, say that you're writing a request to create that post.

```
post-requests
  $pushid
    title: "..."
    body: "..."
```

Then your Cloud Functions code processing this request, writes the actual blog post, writes the fanned-out data, deletes the request and then finally, writes a response back to the client:

```
post-responses
  $pushid: "ok"
```

The trick here is that the request and the response use the same push ID. So as soon as the client has pushed its request, it knows where its response will eventually show up.

Now from the client's perspective, it:

1. Pushes the request to the database
2. Starts listening for the response on the response queue
3. Processes the response

While this approach seems over the top here, it can be useful for longer asynchronous processes where you can't/don't want to keep a single HTTP request open between the client and the server while your request is being processed.

Comment: Interesting, this was how I designed my solution right before I posted the question. I was just hoping for a quicker solution. I guess it's kinda awkward to build a built in firebase solution because as Doug mentioned, onWrite is just picking up the write event and execute as a simple subscriber to that write event/action. Thank you very much!

Comment: The downside here is if the client fails to pick up the response (because it dies and can't resume what it was previously doing), a lot of responses will get collected up in the response area, which will cost you money over time if you don't find a way to clean them up.

Comment: I also talk about this approach here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWj6dxfN63g&t=690s

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible for a database write to wait for the completion of some Cloud Function.  Writes don't know anything about Cloud Functions - the write just becomes an event for the function to consume some time later.

If you need to wait for the completion of a Cloud Function, it'll be much easier if you write it as an HTTPS trigger and invoke it directly from the client, sending a response back only when it's done.  Send the data to post in the request, and have the function be responsible for doing all the actual database writes.

Comment: I sort of wanted to avoid this since I would also like to use Database Rules. This way is too divergent from the "Firebase way" of things. I wanted to do Server-side fanout, even though that would be a bit hacky, to minimize highly complex/redundant database rules for my early stage app. Thank you for the suggestion!